# Bar Chart in Angular JS Using Chartjs

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm making a bar chart using Chartjs in my AngularJS application. I'm able to render the chart, however, I'm not able to find a way to show the value of each bar on top of it. The solutions I found were for Angular apps and not for AngularJs apps.

Here is my canvas tag :

My JS file code:

```
     $scope.labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
    $scope.data = [[75, 63, 59, 79, 13, 91, 113]];
    $scope.ColorBar = ['#90EE90', '#FF6600'];
    $scope.DataSetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }];
    $scope.options = {
        legend: { display: true },
        responsive: true, 
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: 'y-axis-1',
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    position: 'left'
                }]
             }
           }
```

Comment: are you looking for [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels)?

Comment: @Jesper I did come across this plugin but is this the only option available? Or is there any other way of doing it as well?

Answer (score 1):

For this type of feature you should use the [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) which does exactly this.

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      color: 'blue',
      labels: {          
        value: {
          color: 'green'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The documentation is quite good. You should find everything you need there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did come across this option but I was wondering if there is any other way of doing it? One reason being that in the documentation it is mentioned - 'This plugin doesn't provide any public API (except the plugin options), thus you should not access private properties or methods starting with $ or _, including the $datalabels attached property. The implementation can change at any version and could break your production build without notice in upcoming minor/patch releases if any of your code relies on it.'

Comment: I haven't tried @LeeLenalee solution, but it looks like this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use the datalabels plugin you can write your own basic version of it as an inline plugin like so:

```js
const customDatalabalesPlugin = {
  id: 'customDatalabels',
  afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      ctx,
      _metasets
    } = chart;
    const lineHeight = ctx.measureText('M').width;
    const color = opts.color || 'black';

    for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
      const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i)
      meta.data.forEach((el) => {
        //console.log(el)
        const dpVal = el._chart.data.datasets[el._datasetIndex].data[el._index];
        const text = dpVal.toString();
        const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;

        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillText(text, (el._model.x - textWidth / 2), (el._model.y - lineHeight));
      });
    }
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12.4, 19.234, 3.23213, 5.4, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      customDatalabels: {
        color: 'green', // Color each character individual collor
        // color: 'pink' // Color whole label this collor
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customDatalabalesPlugin]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

About using private variables in the plugin, it can be done savely since there wont be another release of version 2 for chart.js so they wont get changed anymore.